# Unrecognized structure in data format 'Rich Text Format'

Tags: c#, xaml, rtf

I want to convert `RTF` to `HTML`. But I get an Error in the `TextRange.Load` Function. I have the following Code:

```
private static string ConvertRtfToXaml(string rtfText)
    {
        var richTextBox = new System.Windows.Controls.RichTextBox();
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(rtfText)) return "";

        var textRange = new TextRange(richTextBox.Document.ContentStart, richTextBox.Document.ContentEnd);

        //Create a MemoryStream of the Rtf content

        using (var rtfMemoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var rtfStreamWriter = new StreamWriter(rtfMemoryStream))
            {
                rtfStreamWriter.Write(rtfText);
                rtfStreamWriter.Flush();
                rtfMemoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

                //Load the MemoryStream into TextRange ranging from start to end of RichTextBox.
                textRange.Load(rtfMemoryStream, System.Windows.Forms.DataFormats.Rtf);
            }
        }

        using (var rtfMemoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {

            textRange = new TextRange(richTextBox.Document.ContentStart, richTextBox.Document.ContentEnd);
            textRange.Save(rtfMemoryStream, System.Windows.DataFormats.Xaml);
            rtfMemoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            using (var rtfStreamReader = new StreamReader(rtfMemoryStream))
            {
                return rtfStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }

    }
```

The Function `textRange.Load(rtfMemoryStream, System.Windows.Forms.DataFormats.Rtf);` throws the following Error:

> Unrecognized structure in data format 'Rich Text Format'.
>   Parameter name: stream

My RTF string looks like this:

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang1031{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0Arial;}}\viewkind4\uc1\pard\fs20 Hallo\par
\par
Wir bitten um Auftragsbest\''e4tigung und Liefertermin\fs20\par
}
```

The RTF string looks normal to me, where is the Parameter stream?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RTF is invalid, as it contains `\''e4` - there are two apostrophes here when there should be only one.

[RTF Special Characters](http://www.biblioscape.com/rtf15_spec.htm#Heading46)

> `\'hh`    A hexadecimal value, based on the specified character set (may be used to identify 8-bit values).

Answer (score 1):

You have a wrong escape/unescape:

```
\''
```

Change it to

```
\'
```

And the `TextRange.Load` should be:

```
textRange.Load(rtfMemoryStream, System.Windows.DataFormats.Rtf);
```

with [`System.Windows.DataFormats.Rtf`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dataformats.rtf(v=vs.110).aspx) defined in the assembly `PresentationCore`.